# Angular Unit Testing - Is there an advantage to calling ngOnDestroy() or fixture.destroy()?

Tags: angular, jestjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have seen the practice of manually destroying the component in `afterEach()` with something like the following:

```
afterEach() {
  component.ngOnDestroy();
  // or fixture.destroy();
}
```

Is there a performance enhancement in doing this? I couldn't see in the documentation any concern for destroying a component after each unit test. Does it speed up a large batch of unit tests running? Are there memory leaks otherwise while other tests continue to run? Is there a difference for `jest` vs `jasmine+karma`?

Comment: Hey, did you get an answer on that?